# Scikit-learn train_test_split blocked

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter

I am trying to split a dataframe with this shape

```
print(a_X_2g_array.shape)
(31371, 120436)
```

and a truth series with this shape

```
 print(a_classes.shape)
 (31371,)
```

Then I try to split it

```
X3g_train, X3g_test, y3g_train, y3g_test = train_test_split(a_X_2g_array, a_classes, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

the `train_test_split` doesn't end and the jupyter notebook says the kernel will be restarted

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I had the same problem with a large data set , its maybe unwise but I first  manually concatenate data with its label and then used train_test_split , its worth to try

Comment: Can you post an output of `print(pd.value_counts(a_X_2g_array.dtypes))`? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: What version of scikit are you using. Can you check this scenario on any of the [examples given in official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#examples-using-sklearn-model-selection-train-test-split). Just make random arrays of `size (31371, 120436)` and try on it.

Comment: @MaxU I have tried to print it but it is a numpy array and it doesn't have the dtypes attribute